# Screen flicker with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg

I am relatively new to Linux and installed Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot with Windows 7 on my Dell laptop. I am having a lot of issues with my screen flickering. I've seen this question asked before but have yet to see a solution.

Hardware:

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4  
Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile  
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Also have an AMD Radeon HD6400m/7400M Series graphics card using the X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati driver which the *Additional Drivers* tab tells me is the recommended driver.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Linux. In the beginning I also had the same problem. The problem is due to some key is pressing automatically.

One way to sort out this problem is type the below command in a terminal,

```
xinput --set-prop 8 "Device Enabled" 0
```

You can keep this in your startup applications later.